# JQuery selector for blank SELECT elements?

Tags: jquery

I want to highlight all selects with no selected values in my html. For what I can see for similar questions, my selector is right, however it doesn't work.

What is wrong with it?

```
$('[value=""]').addClass('fill-field');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$("input, select").change(function(){ // as from your prev. question
if($(this).val() == ''){
    $(this).addClass('fill-field');
} else {
    $(this).removeClass('fill-field');
}
});
```

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nwbY7/36/)**

Comment: This seems like it could work. The problem is that it's a listener. I need to run it only at a particular time. (can't add the class every time a field is blank)

Comment: Is there a way to run this only once?

Comment: @Liso22, yes but when you need to run, if you want to run it on submit then you should go though the `.each` loop.

Comment: @Liso22, check the demo fiddle

Answer (score 0):

`<select>`s don't have a `value` attribute -  their `<option>`s do. So, you can't do this with just an attribute selector. Use `.filter()`.

```
$('select').filter(function ()
{
    return !$(this).val();
}).addClass('fill-field');
```

---

However, it sounds like you're doing some client-side form validation. [Might I suggest *not* reinventing the wheel?](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation)

Answer (score 0):

**Working Demo** **Select demo** http://jsfiddle.net/QF5QJ/ - http://jsfiddle.net/8hQPS/

Hope it fits the cause `:)

**Sample Code**

```
var $selects = $("select").filter(function(i) {
    return $.trim($(this).attr("value")) == '';
});

$selects.css({
    background: 'orange'
});​
```

**OR**

```
var $tds = $("td").filter(function(i) {
    return $.trim($(this).attr("value")) == '';
});

$tds.css({
    background: 'orange'
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
// add the rule here
 $.validator.addMethod("valueNotEquals", function(value, element, arg){
  return arg != value;
 }, "Value must not equal arg.");

 // configure your validation
 $("form").validate({
 rules: {
   SelectName: { valueNotEquals: "default" }
  },
  messages: {
   SelectName: {
    valueNotEquals: "Please select an item!"
   }
  }  
 });
```

Or simply you can apply your class like this:

```
// add the rule here
 $.validator.addMethod("valueNotEquals", function(value, element, arg){
  return arg != value;
 }, "Value must not equal arg.");

 // configure your validation
 $("form").addClass('fill-field');
```